# How can I make a Post Request on Python with urllib3?

Tags: python, json, curl, urllib3

I've been trying to make a request to an API, I have to pass the following body:

```
{
"description":"Tenaris",
"ticker":"TS.BA",
"industry":"Metalúrgica",
"currency":"ARS"
}
```

Altough the code seems to be right and it finished with "Process finished with exit code 0", it's not working well. I have no idea of what I'm missing but this is my code:

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
http.urlopen('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/assets', headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'},
                 data={
"description":"Tenaris",
"ticker":"TS.BA",
"industry":"Metalúrgica",
"currency":"ARS"
})
```

By the way, this the first day working with Python so excuse me if I'm not specific enough.

Comment: Try settings the return value of `http.urlopen()` to a variable and printing it.

Comment: Also, are you running this in an interactive interpreter? or a script?

Answer (score 42):

Since you're trying to pass in a JSON request, you'll need to encode the body as JSON and pass it in with the `body` field.

For your example, you want to do something like:

```
import json
encoded_body = json.dumps({
        "description": "Tenaris",
        "ticker": "TS.BA",
        "industry": "Metalúrgica",
        "currency": "ARS",
    })

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

r = http.request('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/assets',
                 headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                 body=encoded_body)

print r.read() # Do something with the response?
```

*Edit: My original answer was wrong. Updated it to encode the JSON. Also, related question: [How do I pass raw POST data into urllib3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233001/how-do-i-pass-raw-post-data-into-urllib3)*

Comment: It doesn't appear that `fields` will encode the body as JSON which is what I think OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue when making a call to Gitlab CI. Since the above did not work for me (gave me some kind of error about not being able to concatenate bytes to a string), and because the arguments I was attempting to pass were nested, I thought I would post what ended up working for me:

```
API_ENDPOINT = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{}/pipeline".format(GITLAB_PROJECT_ID)

API_TOKEN = "SomeToken"

data = {
    "ref": ref,
    "variables": [
        {
            "key": "ENVIRONMENT",
            "value": some_env
        },
        {   "key": "S3BUCKET",
            "value": some_bucket
        },
    ]
}

req_headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'PRIVATE-TOKEN': API_TOKEN,
}

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

encoded_data = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')

r = http.request('POST', API_ENDPOINT,
             headers=req_headers,
             body=encoded_data)

resp_body = r.data.decode('utf-8')
resp_dict = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))

logger.info('Response Code: {}'.format(r.status))
logger.info('Response Body: {}'.format(resp_body))

if 'message' in resp_body:
    logfile_msg = 'Failed Gitlab Response-- {} {message}'.format(r.status, **resp_dict)
```

Comment: The reason that the top-voted answer doesn't work for you (and me) is because we need to manually encode query parameters in the URL. You can see my answer if you're still interested.

Answer (score -3):

I recently became interested in using `urllib3`, and came across this problem. If you read the `urllib3` "[User Guide](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html)" page, you will see this:

> For POST and PUT requests, you need to manually encode query parameters in the URL

Your code should be adjusted to look like this:

```
import urllib3
from urllib.parse import urlencode

data = {"description":"Tenaris",
        "ticker":"TS.BA",
        "industry":"Metalúrgica",
        "currency":"ARS"}

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
encoded_data = urlencode(data)
http.request('POST',
             'http://localhost:8080/assets?'+encoded_data,
             headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'})
```

Comment: the question is about body, not query parameters. This way you add request query string which is not the way how you pass JSON body