# How can i post XML with urllib3

Tags: python, xml, urllib3

I create a sms gateway with GSM Modem that support Hilink. i stuck in to post XML. first step is get session and token. second. with token pass to header. it will granted access to send message. but, how to pass XML Data with urllib3?

```
import urllib3
import xml.etree.ElementTree as XML

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

response_body = http.request('GET', 'http://192.168.8.1/api/webserver/SesTokInfo')

tree = XML.ElementTree(XML.fromstring(response_body.data))
root = tree.getroot()

token = root[1].text

data="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><request><Index>-1</Index><Phones><Phone>Number</Phone></Phones><Sca></Sca><Content>test</Content><Length>4</Length><Reserved>1</Reserved><Date>-1</Date></request>"

send_message = http.request('POST', 'http://192.168.8.1/api/sms/send-sms', data=data, headers={'__RequestVerificationToken': token, 'Content-Type': 'application/xml'})

print(send_message.status)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I send an xml body using requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509888/how-can-i-send-an-xml-body-using-requests-library)

Comment: @ZKDev i already that post. its not same. that post use request module. i need to use urllib3. i get error __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'. its like data inside request is not exist in urllib3 module.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233001/how-do-i-pass-raw-post-data-into-urllib3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778800/how-can-i-make-a-post-request-on-python-with-urllib3

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `body` parameter instead:

```
send_message = http.request('POST', 'http://192.168.8.1/api/sms/send-sms', body=data, headers={'__RequestVerificationToken': token, 'Content-Type': 'application/xml'})
```